# How to install Intel Simics from the CLI?

Tags: simics

The documentation states that one can install from the terminal using a ispm bundle (*.ispm).
However, the ispm executable reports the following:

`error: unknown option '--install-bundle'`

When running: `ispm --install-bundle /path/simics-6-packages-2021-16-linux64.ispm`

The installation directory has been set using `ispm config install-dir /path/install` as per documentation, and I even tried using the --install-dir flag, but I ended up on the same issue.

Am I missing any other non-documented requirements perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

Please try adding the command "packages"

./ispm packages --install-bundle </path/to/simics-6-packages-2021-16-linux64.ispm>

optionally, consider adding the "--trust-unsigned-packages", "--non-interactive" and "--install-dir"

[Screenshot of Simcis CLI installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sg5kJ.png)

Comment: once installed, I also suggest making sure gtk2 is installed before start using the Simics GUI.

Comment: It's worth clarifying that the use of `--install-dir` is only necessary if you want to override the install directory that is stored in the configuration, as @dom mentioned in their original post. It helps with being explicit though. You should also never have to specify `--trust-unsigned-packages` for bundles that come from official sources, like Intel or Wind River.